# implicit declaration of function ‘mygets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] mygets(str1);

Tags: c

[I've been looking at other questions and none of the solutions have worked so I'll ask my own question.

I'm working on a Ubuntu Kylin16.04(China version) and having trouble compiling my code, here are my gets function, the error received by the compiler][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvpyP.png)

Comment: where is your code? helps to include it in your question so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Paste the code into the question. Don't link it as an image.

Comment: We get questions about implicit function declaration warnings regularly.  The answer is always a variation on "ensure that a declaration of the function is in scope at the point of the call."  Since there is really only one answer, I find it difficult to believe that your review of such questions did not lead you to that answer.  If nevertheless it didn't, then it's unlikely that giving the same answer again will help you, either.

Comment: Your code calls a function called `mygets`. You need to provide a declaration of that function before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit declaration of function means that you don't have function reference somewhere in header file normally.

Or maybe you have it, but the file where your function is called does not see this.

```
//Declaration, must always be before first function call
void myfunc(void);

//Function usage somewhere in the code
int main(void) {
   //Call it here, compiler see the reference and knows what type
   //of func it is and what parameters should be used to func
   myfunc();
}

//Definition, write function content here
//This part will be compiled in separate way, linked will put everything together
void myfunc(void) {
   //Write function content here
}
```

Comment: Your use of "declare" and "define" in the context of C/C++ seems to be mixed up. Those terms are not the same and are clearly defined. "declare" is what you call "reference" in this example and "define" is what you call "declare".

Comment: @riodoro1 is now ok?